# How is it Possible to Generate Tables and Graphs Optimizing the Associated Shichman-Hodges Slope $λ_j$ and Verify the Regression Approach

Tags: calculus, optimization, graphing-functions, regression

## 1. Introduction

Linear regression Equations for $λ_j$ are derived here:

> [How is it Possible to Optimize the Shichman-Hodges Slope Parameters from the Left and Right using Least Square Linear Regression Approaches](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4836964/how-is-it-possible-to-optimize-the-shichman-hodges-slope-parameters-from-the-lef)

as a function of table elements like the following.  A table of some real sample data is found below:
$$ \text{ } $$

| $ X_{V\text{ }SD}\left(Volts\right) $ | $Y_{I\text{ }SD}(Amps) $ | $ I_{SD\text{ hand-modeled}} $ | $\frac{ΔY}{ΔX} $ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.00000000 | 0.71261233 | 0.70234478 | 0.71261233 |
| 1.12515652 | 0.77522725 | 0.76905370 | 0.50029284 |
| 1.25814426 | 0.83691174 | 0.83474886 | 0.46383569 |
| 1.41560924 | 0.89661342 | 0.90561485 | 0.37914252 |
| 1.58292711 | 0.96057391 | 0.97267991 | 0.38226956 |
| 1.78104079 | 1.01345909 | 1.04109907 | 0.26694372 |
| 1.99155068 | 1.03700638 | 1.10071766 | 0.11185810 |
| 2.24080634 | 1.08575487 | 1.15384483 | 0.19557653 |
| 2.50565815 | 1.11098194 | 1.18949735 | 0.09524947 |
| 2.81925774 | 1.14553201 | 1.20392942 | 0.11017279 |
| 3.17210603 | 1.17214799 | 1.20527661 | 0.07543153 |
| 3.54703307 | 1.18115664 | 1.20670807 | 0.02402785 |
| 3.99096727 | 1.18115664 | 1.20840311 | 0.00000000 |
| 4.46267939 | 1.20860028 | 1.21020412 | 0.05817875 |
| 5.02121258 | 1.19938219 | 1.21233678 | -0.01650394 |
| 5.61469460 | 1.20860028 | 1.21460271 | 0.01553207 |
| 6.31741047 | 1.19938219 | 1.21728575 | -0.01311768 |
| 7.06409597 | 1.21788907 | 1.22013676 | 0.02478532 |
| 7.94821405 | 1.23668146 | 1.22351241 | 0.02125556 |
| 8.88765240 | 1.22724938 | 1.22709930 | -0.01004023 |
| 10.00000000 | 1.24618614 | 1.23134637 | 0.01702422 |

$$\textbf{Table 1.1  Real Sample Data and Hand Optimization of the Shichman-Hodges Slope $λ_j$}$$

The question here is: how is it possible generate the tables and graphs of the optimized plots and to verify the optimization formulas previously derived in the [linked formula derivation reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4836964/how-is-it-possible-to-optimize-the-shichman-hodges-slope-parameters-from-the-lef)?

Ideally after presentation of ideal tables and graphs, then the corresponding Shichman-Hodges parameters can be graphed and then applied in a Level 1 Spice Simulation graph for that corresponding [IRF9510 PMOS transistor model](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91072/91072.pdf), with identical results.